# Swift Array(string) not working

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, literals

I'm trying to make a hangman game. I'm going to paste my code in because I feel my problem is somewhere in here that I'm just not seeing. Look down and find the part where I wrote THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS. Here is the error message I get: Missing argument label 'arrayLiteral' in call. When I add the arrayLiteral the code does not work. I'm very new to Swift so some help would be very appreciated! Thank you! (sorry that there's a lot of code that's probably unrelated to the issue)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var secret_word_label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var guess_field: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var submit_button: UIButton!

    //only for bug testing
    @IBOutlet weak var arb_print: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var print_secret: UILabel!

    var user_guesses = [String]()

    var secret_word = "asdf"

    var wrong_guesses = 0

    var guess_letter = ""

    var correct_guesses = 0

    let limit_wrongs = 3

    var secret_word_loc = [String]()


    func return_len(text: String) -> Int {

        var final = [String]()

        var loc = Array(text)

        for letter in loc {

            if !contains(final, String(letter)) {

                final.append(String(letter))

                }

        }

        return final.count

    }


    func gen_secret_word() -> String {

        var random_num = arc4random_uniform(4)

        var words = ["hello","world","iphone","apple"]

        return words[Int(random_num)]

    }


    func start_game(action: UIAlertAction! = nil) {

        secret_word = gen_secret_word()

        print_secret.text = secret_word

        secret_word_label.text = dashes_except(secret_word,except: "1")


       THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS <


        secret_word_loc = Array(secret_word)


        >
        user_guesses = [String]()

        correct_guesses = 0

        wrong_guesses = 0



    }


    func dashes_except(word: String,except: String) -> String {

        var loc = [String]()

        for (index, character) in enumerate(word) {

            loc.append(String(character))

        }

        var loc_except = [String]()

        for (index, character) in enumerate(except) {

            loc_except.append(String(character))

        }

        for x in 0..<loc.count {

            if !contains(loc_except, loc[x]) {

                loc[x] = "-"

            }

        }

        return "".join(loc)

    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true

    }


    @IBAction func submit_engaged(sender: UIButton) {

        guess_letter = guess_field.text

        if contains(user_guesses, guess_letter) {

            var nuttin = "well nuttin"

        }

        else if contains(secret_word_loc, guess_letter) {

            correct_guesses += 1

            user_guesses.append(guess_letter)

        } else {

            wrong_guesses += 1

            user_guesses.append(guess_letter)

        }



        arb_print.text = "".join(user_guesses)

        secret_word_label.text = dashes_except(secret_word,except: "".join(user_guesses))

        if correct_guesses == return_len(secret_word) {

            //give alert that they won and then ask for continue to play again and put how many guesses it took them


            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "You won", message: "Congrats. It took you \(wrong_guesses + correct_guesses) tries", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: start_game))

            presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)


        }

        else if wrong_guesses == limit_wrongs {

            //give alert that they lost and then ask for continue to play again and give the word

            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "You lost", message: "The word was \(secret_word)", preferredStyle: .Alert)

            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Play Again", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: start_game))

            presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }









    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        guess_field.delegate = self

        start_game()

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: It looks to me that he is actually trying to make an array of characters. Changing secret_word_loc to `[Character]` I think is what he is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you declared `secret_word_loc` as a type of `Array<String>`, and `Array<secret_word>` is actually a type of `Array<Character>`. You could either declare `var secret_word_loc = [Character]()` or do `secret_word_loc  = map("secret_word") {String($0)}` which will convert each character in `secret_word` to `String` and put them in an `Array`.

Comment: The suggested code not only doesn't even remotely resolve the askers problem, but it also doesn't even compile (unless it compiles on Xcode 7... I only tested this on Xcode 6.3.whatever, but it definitely doesn't work there).  How you have an upvote for this answer baffles me.

Comment: Thank you everyone who left an answer. Eric Qian, your solution to use map worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Try `secret_word_loc = [secret_word]`.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two possible solutions here, as `Array` has several initializers.

First, we can use the literal array syntax, which is simply a pair of square brackets wrapped around our comma-separated array elements:

```
secret_word_loc = [secret_word]
```

Or, we can use the more verbose initializer, which actually explains the source of the error message:

```
secret_word_loc = Array(arrayLiteral: secret_word)
```

This initializer for `Array` accepts a comma-separated list of array elements to instantiate your array with.

Both solutions work perfectly fine.

The second explains the error message:

> Missing argument label 'arrayLiteral'

which is simply telling you "Hey, everything is right, but you *must* use the argument label, which in this case is `arrayLiteral`.

The first solution, however, is more Swift-esque and I'd absolutely prefer seeing that in any code I'm maintaining.